# Django, Grunt, and S3: Possible to have image URLs in CSS?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, gruntjs

I'm working with Django 1.7 and I am using Grunt to compile SASS and perform other tasks. Previously I was using Django with Compress, and this allowed me to pass in `{{ STATIC_URL }}` (declared in settings.py) to handle image URLs. For example:

```
background: url('{{STATIC_URL}}images/background.png');
```

However, now that I am using Grunt to deal with compiling the SASS, it is no longer possible to use variables in my SASS files. I was wondering what the best way would be to handle this? I can't use relative paths because I am deploying on S3, and thus when I push to production it will not preserve the right URL syntax.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could benefit from a Grunt plugin that rewrites urls (like [grunt-css-url-rewrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-url-rewrite)), so you could leave the urls as relative without any special tokens. Add that task to your production build task, it will prepend/change paths however you configure it to.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Looks like it might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sure. I'll probably write something of my own soon, possible a fork of https://github.com/hollandben/grunt-cache-bust - As the css-url-rewrite plugin doesn't cover all places a url can go. Will update here if and when that happens.